# Amcharts label are overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I am new to AmCharts ,my sample codes with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sjyx79u/1/). Facing a problem in Title overlapping in the chart.Is their any way to solve it ???

```
 var chart;
    var legend;    
    var chartData = [
    {Fund:'Strategic Income' , value: 1014},{Fund:'UK & International Income' , value: 649},{Fund:'UK Equity' , value: 647},{Fund:'Global Equity Income' , value: 639},{Fund:'Equity Income' , value: 634},{Fund:'UK Income' , value: 390},{Fund:'Diversified Bond' , value: 379},{Fund:'Property' , value: 377},{Fund:'Investment Grade Corporate Bond' , value: 251},{Fund:'Corporate Bond' , value: 127}

        ];

    AmCharts.ready(function() {
        // PIE CHART
        chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
        chart.dataProvider = chartData;
        chart.titleField = "country";
        chart.valueField = "value";
        chart.percentFormatter = { precision: 1, decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',' };
            chart.outlineThickness = 1;
            chart.labelText = "[[percents]]%";
            chart.hideLabelsPercent = 2.044444;
            chart.labelRadius = 35;
            chart.startRadius = "0%"; //start explode
            chart.pullOutRadius = "20%";
            chart.depth3D = 15;
            chart.angle = 40;

            chart.sequencedAnimation = false;
            chart.startDuration = 0;


        // WRITE
        chart.write("chartdiv");
    });
```

[image: percentage label are overlapping]

Answer (score 0):

you can update it as per you can write

```
chart.balloonFunction = function(graphDataItem, graph) {
      return graphDataItem.dataContext.Fund + ' :\u00a3'+ graphDataItem.value;
    };
```

to change overlapping 
add some field which will specify distance and provide that field in **lableRadiusField** working code is there in fiddle. ;-)

```
chart.labelRadiusField ='labelRadius';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MehulJoshi/6sjyx79u/10/

Comment: is their any way to prevent the overlapping of the Labels Percent??

Comment: Ok let me check will have to look into it

Comment: see this fiddle for the updated answer. http://jsfiddle.net/MehulJoshi/6sjyx79u/10/

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of `chart.balloonText = "[[title]]:\u00a3[[value]]\n[[description]]";` to `chart.balloonText = "[[Fund]]:\u00a3[[value]]\n[[description]]";`

Comment: is their any way to prevent the overlapping of the Labels Percent??

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a consistent way to prevent overlapping while showing all labels.

You can use the `labelRadiusField` like @MehuJoshi pointed out, but that's dependent on your chart's dimensions and other settings. Also, if you have additional slices that are similar in size, you'll have to keep setting additional radii in your data for the `labelRadiusField`.

You can also tweak the chart [`radius`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#radius) - making it bigger or smaller will shift the labels around a bit, provided your chart div's dimensions are sufficient:

`chart.radius = "40%";`

[Here's a fiddle illustrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/6sjyx79u/11/). Again, this isn't foolproof like the `labelRadiusField`, since it depends on your sizing.

A cleaner solution would be to outright hide smaller labels by setting [`hideLabelsPercent`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#hideLabelsPercent) to a upper threshold percent value (for example, hide labels for slices smaller than 5%) and set a legend instead, which will show all labels separately.

```
  chart.hideLabelsPercent = 5;
  chart.legend = { enabled: true, position: "right" };
```

[Here's a fiddle illustrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/6sjyx79u/13/). Note that I updated your titleField to point to the `Fund` property instead of `country`, which doesn't exist in your data. I also customized the [`valueText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueText) to show both the value and percentage of the slice.

Also, just a heads up that you were using an older version of AmCharts (v2.11.3). Both @MehuJoshi's fiddle and my fiddle use the latest version in the v3 branch.